# How to use global variable in a jquery function whose value was initially assigned on ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML code :

```
<input type="hidden" id="rowcountforuser" value="0"/>
<button id="buttonid" onClick="increaseRowCount()">submit</button>
```

Here is my jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var countrows;
  $(document).ready(function(){
      countrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('rowcountforuser').value);
  });
function increaseRowCount(){
countrows++;
alert(countrows);
}
</script>
```

I want that each time i clicked on 'Submit' button, value of 'countrows' variable should get increase, but application is each time displaying the value of 'countrows' as '1' in alert box.

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you make a Fiddle where you replicate the problem.

Comment: code looks good to me also. Are you submitting form and reloading page again in your actual code.. just want to confirm.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/btLB9/

Comment: @Bhushan Kawadkar...i am not submitting the form, but code is not working for me..:(

Answer (score 0):

**Remove** below line from your code

```
 countrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('rowcountforuser').value);
```

And **Replace** it with

```
countrows = $("#rowcountforuser").val();
            $("#buttonid").click(increaseRowCount);
```

Check this **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gagan_Gami/ew3ZU/14/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var countrows;
$(document).ready(function(){
      countrows = parseInt(document.getElementById('rowcountforuser').value);
    $("#buttonid").click(function(){
        countrows+=1;
       alert(countrows);
    });
});
```

Here is working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninad/Ls7zG/) link of code